# Xampp: cannot create virtual host

Tags: apache, xampp

I am trying to create virtual hosts using xampp, but the new urls I create cannot be reached in the browsers.
**Apache vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


 <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/onetone/public"
   ServerName cms.dev
 </VirtualHost>
```

**Hosts**

```
 127.0.0.1  cms.dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open file httpd-vhosts.conf then you search line ##NameVirtualHost *:80
- Delete "##" before NameVirtualHost *:80
- Finall, you paste your virtualhost